# Validation issues with localization using UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, localization

Basically I have localized a website by using gettext(), and used the UTF-8 character encoding format.

1. Can anybody suggest me that there will be issue in validation of form (like length of the field) in UTF-8 ?
2. can UTF-8 is sufficient to manage  HTML special characters or entity?
3. Can the translated string in UTF-8 format be stored in database?

Please suggest me if any issue occurs.
 Thanks.....

Comment: I mean,will there be any issue in use of html special characters?

Comment: @Sam: What language are you using?

Comment: @Thanatos- I am using text in english and transelated the text in to german

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to accept data in UTF-8 and do validation on it that requires looking at individual *characters*, you'll need to make sure you use multibyte-aware string functions to work on those characters, like [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) instead of `strlen`.
2. All characters relevant for HTML are still identical to their ASCII equivalent, so there's nothing special about substituting HTML special chars. You should just make sure to set the `$encoding` parameter of `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`.
3. Sure. Just make sure your database can store UTF-8 and you have set the database *connection* to UTF-8 so your database expects to receive UTF-8 encoded data. Google `SET NAMES utf8`.